# ASP.Net Core MVC Model Value Not Set From Select Box

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to follow the example shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-select-tag-helper).  It is a simple select (combo box).

Here is the code for my model:

```
public class TestHarnessViewModel
{
    public TestHarnessViewModel(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var hostname = ApiGateway.GetApiGatewayHost();
        var apiContext = configuration["AppSettings:TestHarnessApiContext"];
        var localHostname = $"localhost:{configuration["AppSettings:TestHarnessServicePort"]}";
        
        HostTypes = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Value = localHostname, Text = "locally hosted"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = $"{hostname}/{apiContext}", Text = "API Gateway"}
        };

        HostName = localHostname;
    }

    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> HostTypes { get; }
}
```

And this is the code in my view:

```
@model TestHarnessViewModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"></div>
    <select asp-for="HostName" asp-items="Model.HostTypes"></select>
</div>
```

And in the controller I make an instance of `TestHarnessViewModel` in the constructor and set it as a class level variable (called `model`) .  I then pass it into the view where needed.  (`Return View(model)` or `Return View("Index", model)`)

This seems to work fine from the UI.  I get a Select box with the two options, and I can pick one.  But when I try to reference the `model.HostName` in the controller, the HostName is always null.  (Or when I default the value in code, it stays at the default value.)

I read that I might need to add `[BindProperty]` on `HostName`.  But I tried that and it did not have any effect on the result (it stayed at null/default value.)

**How can I get the value the user selects in the UI to be set to to model?**  (In my example the property called `HostName`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't get something like the following when you do the form post (I assume that's what you're trying to do?)

```
InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'TestHarnessViewModel'.
Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a 
parameterless constructor. Alternatively. give the 'model' parameter a non-null default value.
```

It said everything there. Your view model needs to have a parameter-less constructor, which makes sense because a view model is just meant to be a Data Transfer Object.

Change your view model to the following:

```cs
public class TestHarnessViewModel
{
    public string HostName { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> HostTypes { get; set; }
}
```

and initialize it in your controller:

```cs
public class HarnessController : Controller
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public HarnessController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
         _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var hostname = ApiGateway.GetApiGatewayHost();
        var apiContext = _configuration["AppSettings:TestHarnessApiContext"];
        var localHostname = $"localhost:{_configuration["AppSettings:TestHarnessServicePort"]}";

        var vm = new TestHarnessViewModel
        {
            HostTypes = new List<SelectListItem>
            {
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = localHostname, 
                    Text = "locally hosted"
                },
                new SelectListItem 
                {
                    Value = $"{hostname}/{apiContext}", 
                    Text = "API Gateway"
                }
            },
            HostName = localHostname
        };

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use EditorFor html helper